# automatic resize the tag when content overflows in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am placing the content in `<p>` tag.

I've specified the width and height of the `<p>` tag initially.When the content appends dynamically,The content may be large and it overflows to the `<p>` tag.

But I observed in case of IE it automatically increases the `<p>` size when content overflow occurs.But incase of other browsers content will be appended outside the `<p>` tag.

What is the solution for these browsers for automatic resize the tag?

Answer (score 0):

Set a min-width and min-height on the `<p>` tags instead of height and width:

```
p {
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Earlier versions of IE will helpfully ignore these properties...so you'll need to continue setting height and width in an [IE only style sheet](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html):

```
p {
    /* behaves like min-height in IE */
    height: 100px; 

    /* min-width css expression */ 
    width: expression(this.width < 101 ? "100px" : this.width);  
}
```